# Pandas - replace row with null values and drop rows matching two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dataframe where I take a subset of columns and then want to filter out the rows that conditionally match two criterias.

Heres what the dataframe looks like:

```
Name     Err1    Err2    Page 
Amazon   404     201     Shopping
Facebook 202             Social
Goku                     Shopping
Ross             203     Shopping
```

I replace the nulls with say '-' group the data with Err1 and Err2, and also get the unique count of Err1.

```
    df['err1'].fillna("-", inplace=True)
    df['err2'].fillna("-", inplace=True)
    df.groupby(["Name","Err1", "Err2"]).agg({"Err1": "count"})
```

This gives me:

```
Name     Err1    Err2    Err1 
Amazon   404     201     1
Facebook 202      -      1
Goku      -       -      1
Ross      -      203     1
```

a) I would like to remove all rows that have both "Err1" and "Err2" == "-" and display rows only if either Err1 or Err2 are not '-'.

b) In the above, how can I get the unique count of both Err1 and Err2 combined, instead of the unique of just Err1?

I dont want to use for loops and iterate through the data as the dataset is over 100k lines. Is there an efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you fill the nulls with `-`.  It would be easier if you left them as is.

Comment: The groupby seems to be ignoring fields with null values. Correct me if I am doing something wrong. Thanks

Comment: > *I would like to remove all rows that have both "Err1" and "Err2" == "-" and display rows only if either Err1 or Err2 are not '-'.*; don't replace `NaN`' values with `-` and just `df.dropna(how='all', subset=['Err1', 'Err2'])`

Comment: `df = df.loc[~((df['Err1'] == "-") & (df['Err2'] == "-")), :]` if you just have to turn them into dashes

Comment: Sweet! Thanks guys! Thats good learning for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way first you need to `dropna` when Errs are all null

```
df=df[df[['Err1','Err2']].isnull().all(1)].copy()
```

About the unique count , when you `groupby` with `Err1` and `Err2`, it already getting the `count` by both of them

```
df.fillna('NaN').groupby(["Name","Err1", "Err2"]).size()
```